# Child process killing itself but becoming zombie

Tags: raspberry-pi, c++

I need to turn on a GPIO on my Raspberry Pi for a certain amount of time, so I made a function creating a child process, turning the GPIO on for some time then off. Problem is, when I try to make the child process kill itself, it stays around as a zombie. This function is executed quite a lot so it can't stay that way. Anyone have a solution for this ? Thx

`void my_function(GPIOClass* gpio,useconds_t time)   {
pid_t pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)  {
        signal(SIGALRM,killchild)
        gpio->setval_gpio("1");
        usleep(time*1000);
        gpio->setval_gpio("0");
        alarm(3);
        while(1);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reap the child process from the parent. See `wait(2)`. What seems to be happening is that you are just handling the case where the child process code is executed, and simply ignoring the result in the parent. As a result, the parent doesn't perform any cleanup after the child exits, and leaks PIDs as a result.

The simplest solution is to add the following `else` case to the `if` condition.

```
else if (pid > 0) {
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
```

**EDIT**: The above condition will block the parent process until the child completes. When the child exits, the `SIGCHLD` signal is sent to the parent, and by default it is ignored. However, according to POSIX.1-2001, if you explicitly set the signal handler for `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN`, then the system will automatically clean up the child, with the caveat that the parent process will not know anything about the exit status of the child.

In your initialization function, add the following code:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: Well that won't work, because then my main process will still be sleeping until i'm done with the GPIOs, and the point of creating a new process was to keep the parent process going. The result is the same if I don't fork.

Comment: See my edit, you can explicitly ignore SIGCHLD (or add a signal handler to manually cleanup after the child exits).

Comment: Cool that did the trick, thanks a lot !!